Typescript Interface Index Signature
I have the following interface:
interface ClassSchedule {
  [key: string]: string;
}

However, I am receiving an error that my key is possibly undefined. How do I account for this?
interface ClassSchedule {
  [key: string]: string;
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] which demonstrates the error you're talking about. Right now all we see is the interface, but not where the problem you're having resides, so this risks being closed as needing debugging details unless you edit it.

You've accepted an answer but you still haven't provided the [mre]. It's great that you've gotten the help you want. Now please do future readers a favor and give us an example that demonstrates the issue.

It sounds like you have the --noUncheckedIndexedAccess compiler option enabled.
You can avoid this error by:

Disabling that compiler option (though that loses you a bit of type safety).
Checking whether the key exists before trying to access it (e.g. by wrapping the access in an if statement).
Adding an ! after the key (e.g. foo.bar! or `foo["bar"]!) to assert that the value will always be non-null.

